# Trying to change a color in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I asked a question previously about detecting if a chess piece was selected. I was introduced to arrays and now selection is working how I want it to, except for the fact that I cant change the color.

```
public static Color[] pieceColo = new Color[4]
  { PawnBl1Col, PawnBl2Col, PawnBl3Col, PawnBl4Col};
```

This is the array Im fixing up, PawnBl1Col is declared white ( along with all the other values)

```
if (movement.pieceLocX[movement.pLvalX] <= movement.mouseCord.X
 && movement.pieceLocX[movement.pLvalX] + 100 >= movement.mouseCord.X
 && movement.pieceLocY[movement.pLvalY] <= movement.mouseCord.Y
 && movement.pieceLocY[movement.pLvalY] + 100 >= movement.mouseCord.Y)
    movement.pieceColo[movement.pLvalX] = Color.Red;
```

When executed the if statement runs fine, but when it comes to executing its command it fails and does nothing.

```
movement.PawnBl1Col = Color.Red;
```

However if I replaced the color array with the above it works seamlessly.

Edit: Forgot a big part
movement.pLvalX is just an integer that coincides with each object. It tests all 8 values (will be 32).If X object is selected then X object changes color, Im not sure if that makes any sense. But even testing the color array with 0-3 wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawing code, I assume you're using `movement.PawnBl1Col` as the color to draw?

The `movement.pieceColo[movement.pLvalX] = Color.Red;` statement is not changing the value of the `movement.PawnBl1Col` variable. It is actually replacing the entry in the array with `Color.Red`.

Color is a value type. The only way using an array like this will work is if it contains reference types. It's a little untidy but you could try something like this:

```
public class MyColor
{
   public MyColor(Color color)
   {
      this.Color = color;
   }

   public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Use this `MyColor` type for your variables (`PawnBl1Col, PawnBl2Col, PawnBl3Col, PawnBl4Col`) and change your array to...

```
public static MyColor[] pieceColo = new MyColor[4] { PawnBl1Col, PawnBl2Col, PawnBl3Col, PawnBl4Col };
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
movement.pieceColo[movement.pLvalX].Color = Color.Red;
```

And use `movement.PawnBl1Col.Color` in your drawing code.

Comment: Thanks but its not working as the values are counting as null. I need it to default as white, and then be changed to red. I feel like I should be able to figure it out :/

Comment: Try changing MyColor to a struct. Or just make sure you have initialized any instance of it using new MyColor(Color.White)